# Tailwindcss text color changes not always taking effect

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

Good morning,
i'm studying tailwindcss in this period.
But i've got a problem -->
If i change my text color sometime it changes, sometime it doesn’t.
class='flex' doesn’t work, but bg-color does (but not with all the colors).
I copied a project on the official website to be sure wasn’t my fault.
But not everything was working... Is maybe possible i forgot something about the configuration? Should i install something else after the standard config?
I followed the official website's guide.

Comment: It's hard to understand the question as the formating is quite poor and we don't have a lot information to help you. Could you edit the question with a cleaner format and more information like how is TailwindCSS imported, show us your code please.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and I figure out that I forget to add the right paths to all my template files in my tailwind.config.js file.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```